# BigDecimal locale specific parsing - inconsistency between Wicket's BigDecimalConverter and java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, wicket, bigdecimal

When it comes to parsing numbers with decimal separators from string, Wicket's BigDecimalConverter behaves differently than BigDecimal's (String val) constructor.

Let's try to parse a number with comma as the decimal separator using US locale. (I'm using Wicket 1.4.14 BTW.)

---

`new BigDecimalConverter().convertToObject("1,3",  Locale.US)`
returns `13`,

---

but

---

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
new BigDecimal("1,3")
```

throws `NumberFormatException`.

---

Why doesn't BigDecimalConverter behave the same way as BigDecimal in this case? The number "1,3" doesn't make sense for the US locale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` class implements its own validation algorithm on the input, which is throwing the `NumberFormatException`.

The reason why `BigDecimalConverter` is parsing `1,3` as `13` is that it is using a raw `DecimalFormat` behind the scenes. In [`AbstractNumberConverter.parse()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.18/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converters/AbstractNumberConverter.java?av=h#59), the [`getNumberFormat(locale)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.18/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converters/AbstractNumberConverter.java#AbstractNumberConverter.getNumberFormat%28java.util.Locale%29) and [`parse()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.18/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converters/AbstractConverter.java#AbstractConverter.parse%28java.text.Format%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.Locale%29) methods combination boils down to the following snippet, that takes Wicket out of the equation:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal bd = format.parseObject("1,3");
System.out.println(bd.toString()); // Prints 13 !
```

**UPDATE** 
The reason why `DecimalFormat` is ignoring the `,` character is because it is defined as the  grouping separator in the `DecimalFormatSymbols` for the US locale. 
It is permitted, and legal as it would be in `1,300.5`.

In case you want to avoid converting `1,3` to `13`, and throwing a invalid format conversion exception, you could override `BigDecimalConverter.getNumberFormat(Locale)` in order to modify the `DecimalFormat` to not use grouping, use a different grouping symbol, or use a more restrictive pattern. For instance:

```
TextField<BigDecimal> text = new TextField<BigDecimal>(id, model){
    @Override
    public IConverter getConverter(Class<?> type) {
        return new BigDecimalConverter() {
            @Override
            public NumberFormat getNumberFormat(Locale locale) {
                NumberFormat format = super.getNumberFormat(locale);
                format.setGroupingUsed(false);
                return format;
            }
        };
    }
};
text.setType(BigDecimal.class);
```

**Note**: Use the above example with caution, create a class for the Converter so it doesn't get instantiated at each call of `getConverter()` and don't modify the `NumberFormat` instance `BigDecimalConverter.getNumberFormat()` returns, it might be a global shared instance.

Just to add, this is the exact piece of code that's ignoring the `,` character for being a group separator: [`DecimalFormat.subparse()` branch in line 1522](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.java.html#1521). With input of `1,3`, the comma is ignored, being `isGroupingUsed()` true.

Comment: @Chris [`BigDecimalConverter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.17/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converters/BigDecimalConverter.java#44) *doesn't* ignore `Locale`. The code in that wiki example isn't the actual code of the converter. The reasons that it's returning `13` seem specific to `DecimalFormat`

Comment: That was a second exhaustive answer to my question in one day. Thanks a lot, Xavi!